# Issues about adding hyperlinks

Tags: ms-word

I would like to seek help about editing the following macro.

(Prior to conducting my research, I sought advice from experienced VBA experts who suggested a solution. According to their recommendation, I can incorporate a numbered bookmark for each item found. This approach enables the retrieval of the calculated start time in seconds, which can then be assigned back to the corresponding hyperlinks associated with each bookmark. But I am still new to VBA and I am not fully understand that.)

I aim the macro can perform the following tasks:

**1. Using the following code to browse and choose the Excel file (the Excel file contains column A (text) and column B (6-digit numbers)**

```
Dim EXL As Object
Dim xlsWB As Object
Dim xlsPath As String


Set EXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    xlsPath = BrowseForFile("Select Workbook", True)
    If Not xlsPath = vbNullString Then
        Set xlsWB = EXL.Workbooks.Open(xlsPath)

Private Function BrowseForFile(Optional strTitle As String, Optional bExcel As Boolean) As String
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .Title = strTitle
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        If bExcel Then
            .Filters.add "Excel workbooks", "*.xls,*.xlsx,*.xlsm"
        Else
            .Filters.add "Word documents", "*.doc,*.docx,*.docm"
        End If
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo ERR_HANDLER:
        BrowseForFile = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
ERR_HANDLER:
    BrowseForFile = vbNullString
    Resume lbl_Exit
End Function
```

**2. Extract 6-digit numbers from selected Excel file's column B into the macro**

```
'I don't know how to write this part. Here's the code for Extracting 6-digit numbers from Word for your references.


With aRng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[0-9]{6}"
    .MatchWildcards = True`
```

**3. Use the following code to calculate start time**

```
  Dim Hr As Integer
  Dim Mn As Integer
  Dim Sc As Integer
  Dim startTime As Long

    Do While .Execute
      ' Get hours, minutes, and seconds from time marker
      hrs = CInt(Left(aRng.Text, 2))
      mins = CInt(Mid(aRng.Text, 3, 2))
      secs = CInt(Right(aRng.Text, 2))
      startTime = hrs * 3600 + mins * 60 + secs`
```

**4. Enter the meeting ID for merging the link**

```
Dim mtgID As String

mtgID = InputBox

If mtgID = Empty Then
Exit Sub`
```

**5. Add hyperlinks to the names according to selected Excel file's column A**

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=aRng, Address:="https://ABC?meetingid=" & mtgID & "&start=" & startTime
      aRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Those names' format are as follows:

```
With Selection.Find
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.BOLD = True
        .MatchWildcards = True`
```

**Here are the demo files for testing:**

1. Word Document (contain Names)
   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sRHz--7o_OwhzVwcPf1SlKlJAVP5QPpb/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108146638602496496156&rtpof=true&sd=true
2. Excel file (contain column A(Names) and column B (6-digit numbers)
   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1slyC0Ht-qsMnsxGYtDhYWzufU-bq3Tbg/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108146638602496496156&rtpof=true&sd=true

I would like to express my gratitude in advance to anyone who can provide assistance in editing the macro. Thank you!